# SetCursor while dragging files into a window

Tags: c++, winapi, drag-and-drop, cursor

I'm using windows API to create an application with a window only, so everything inside this window is drawn using Direct2D.

Now I want to drop some files in specific parts of my window's client area, and I'm handling the message `WM_DROPFILES`. No problem here, when the files are dropped in those specific areas, I can treat them correctly and everything is working properly. BTW, my window is `DragAcceptFiles(hWnd, true)`, it always accepts drag/drops.

I want the mouse cursor to be different depending on the area of the window the mouse is in. In the areas that I don't treat the drop, I want the cursor to be the invalid icon, and for the areas of the window that I do handle the drops, I want the correct drop icon.

The first thing I noticed is that no message is generated when files are being dragged into the window, and for this reason I added a mouse hook (`WH_MOUSE_LL` using `SetWindowsHookEx`). When the hook is processed, I only look at the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message, so I can change the cursor according to the area the mouse is in.

The problem is that the `SetCursor` does nothing, if my windows is configured to accept drag files, the cursor is always the drag/drop cursor, no matter how many times I call `SetCursor`.

It seems impossible to change the cursor this way, but is there any other way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Controlling the cursor requires implementing the IDropTarget COM interface.

Comment: As Hans said, implement the `IDropTarget` interface, and then set the cursor using `SetCursor()` within the [`DragOver` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: It is not the responsibility of the *drop target* to change the cursor. It is the responsibility of the *drop source* instead. In the target's `IDropTarget::DragEnter()` and `IDropTarget::DragOver()` implementations, it needs to set the `pdwEffect` output parameter to an appropriate `DROPEFFECT` value. That value then gets passed back to the *drop source*, which then displays visual feedback to the user (like changing the cursor) in its `IDropSource::GiveFeedback()` implementation.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: It is possible for `IDropTarget` to be invoked without user interaction (ie, programably from another app), which is why the *source*, not the *target*, decides whether or not to display UI updates to the user.  The *target* does not know (or care) why it is being invoked, only that it is being given some data and asked whether it will accept or reject that data, nothing more.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Fair enough; I haven't used `IDropTarget` and `IDropSource` in practice, I was just going based on my Win32 knowledge and the documentation.  Would you care to post that as an answer?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: answer posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a class in your code that implements the [`IDropTarget`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679679.aspx) interface, then create an instance of that class and pass it to [`RegisterDragDrop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678405.aspx) to associate it with your window.  Do not use `DragAcceptFiles()` anymore.

Whenever the user drags anything (not just files) over your window, your `IDropTarget::DragEnter()` and `IDropTarget::DragOver()`, `IDropTarget::DragLeave()` methods will be called accordingly, giving you the current coordinates of the drag and information about the data being dragged (so you can filter out any data you don't want to accept).  If you choose to accept the data, and the user actually drops the data onto your window, your `IDropTarget::Drop()` method will be called.

As the drop target, it is **not** your responsibility to change the cursor. It is the responsibility of the drop source instead to handle that as needed.  In your `IDropTarget::DragEnter()` and `IDropTarget::DragOver()` implementations, all you need to do is set the `pdwEffect` output parameter to an appropriate [`DROPEFFECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693457.aspx) value.  That value gets passed back to the drop source, which then displays visual feedback to the user (like changing the cursor) in its `IDropSource::GiveFeedback()` implementation.

It is possible for your `IDropTarget` to be invoked without user interaction (ie, programmably from another apps, and not just for drag&drop operations).  That is why the drop source, not the drop target, decides whether or not to display UI updates to the user, since only the drop source knows why it is invoking your `IDropTarget` in the first place.  The drop target does not know (or care) why it is being invoked, only that it is being given some data and asked whether it will accept or reject that data, nothing more.

Refer to MSDN for more details:

[OLE and Data Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693425.aspx)

[Transferring Shell Objects with Drag-and-Drop and the Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776905.aspx)