# How to be notified that user is about to drop a file onto my window

Tags: winapi, mouseevent, mouse

WM_MOUSEMOVE is sent when the mouse is moved over my window, regardless of whether a mouse button is held down or not.

However, **the above is not true if the user is in the process of carrying a file into my window**.

How can I get notified of this special case?

I'm ok with requiring a minimum of Windows 7, or even Windows 10.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856514/setcursor-while-dragging-files-into-a-window) which is almost the same, but I can't implement the `IDropTarget` COM interface, because my project has not been created as an ["ATL COM" app nor as an "MFC application that contains ATL support"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/implementing-an-interface-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019).

**Edit**: I'll try `WH_MOUSE_LL` from the above-linked question.

Comment: COM has no library requirement. You can implement `IDropTarget` in C, if you wish, although C++ makes it easier.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks! Is the linked MS documentation inaccurate then?

Comment: You can act on the [WM_DROPFILES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/wm-dropfiles) message, provided that your application's main window has had this enabled *via* a call to [DragAcceptFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-dragacceptfiles).

Comment: No. It just explains how to implement a COM interface using the ATL. ATL is Microsoft's official support library for COM, but you can use any other library (like WRL or C++/WinRT) or no library at all. COM has [very little requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model): *"The only language requirement for COM is that code is generated in a language that can create structures of pointers and, either explicitly or implicitly, call functions through pointers."*

Comment: The key is to initialise COM and call `RegisterDragDrop`. The interface you supply can be in C, C++ or any other language that can create a compatible interface. You can also use the higher-level `DragAcceptFiles` (or set the appropriate window style) in which case the COM stuff is handled for you.

Comment: Note that `WM_DROPFILES` only works for dragging physical files, whereas `IDropTarget` works for dragging just about any Shell item. Everything about drag&drop under the hood is based on `IDropTarget` and `IDataObject`. If an app does not implement `IDropTarget` then a `WM_DROPFILES` message will be synthesized if the app accepts that and the dragged `IDataObject` contains physical file paths.

Comment: @StefanMonov Is it easier to use `RegisterDragDrop` ([Drag and Drop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/drag-and-drop)) than implement the same logic using mouse input events by yourself? And using hook in product environment is not suggested. Which [platform or application type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/choose-your-platform) are you working on?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Thanks! I am using DragAcceptFiles, but it doesn't seem to let me do what I asked for in the question.

Comment: `DragAcceptFiles` will only send a `WM_DROPFILES` message. This message is sent *after* the user has dropped files. It won't allow you to respond to user actions before that. You'll need `RegisterDragDrop` and an `IDropTarget` for that.